# STI change amongs inherited types.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my models I use STI like this

Vehicle Model: vehicle.rb

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Car Model: car.rb

```
class Car < Vehicle
end
```

Bus Model: bus.rb

```
class Bus < Vehicle
end
```

If I create a Car can I somehow change it's type to Vehicle or Bus?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To permanently alter the type, change the value of the `type` column.

```
c1 = Car.first
c1.name # BMW

c1.update_attribute(:type, "Bus")

b1 = Bus.first
b1.name # BMW
```

To also change the object type in-memory without reloading it from the DB, use "becomes, as in

```
c1 = c1.becomes(Bus)
```

Comment: As an addendum, if you only temporarily want an instance of the other type, you can use `becomes`.

Comment: Setting type fixes for the next load, but you need to use becomes if you want your object to start behaving as the new type immediately.  And becomes sets for immediate use. but the change is not saved with the record.  So changing type 'now and in the future' means setting type AND using becomes.

Comment: As a side note, because I was trying to be clever and failing, you *can't* do `c1=c1.becomes(Bus)` and then `c1.save` because ActiveRecord tries to outsmart you, and it issues an UPDATE query with type equal to the new type, not the old one, so the UPDATE succeeds but is a no-op. I was so excited when I saw that `becomes` updates the type field, but I didn't realize it wasn't saving properly until I looked at the SQL in the console.